# Devise unconfirmed_email when trying to click on confirm account from received email

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, devise, email-confirmation

Here's my user model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
        :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable,:confirmable

  # Setup accessible (or protected) attributes for your model
  attr_accessible :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :remember_me

end
```

Here's the schema.rb:

```
 create_table "users", :force => true do |t|
      t.string   "email",                  :default => "", :null => false
      t.string   "encrypted_password",     :default => "", :null => false
      t.string   "reset_password_token"
      t.datetime "reset_password_sent_at"     
      t.datetime "remember_created_at"
      t.integer  "sign_in_count",          :default => 0
      t.datetime "current_sign_in_at"
      t.datetime "last_sign_in_at"
      t.string   "current_sign_in_ip"
      t.string   "last_sign_in_ip"
      t.string   "confirmation_token"
      t.datetime "confirmed_at"
      t.datetime "confirmation_sent_at"
      t.datetime "created_at",                             :null => false
      t.datetime "updated_at",                             :null => false
      t.integer  "profile_id"
      t.string   "profile_type"
end
```

And in my initializer, devise.rb, I set this:

```
config.reconfirmable = false
```

I receive a mail telling me to click on confirm my account, and when I do, I get this error:

```
NameError in Devise::ConfirmationsController#show

undefined local variable or method `unconfirmed_email' for #<User:0xaa53818>
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: Can you post the full backtrace? :)

Comment: @JoséValim Sure, give me a few minutes to boot into the virtual machine.

Comment: @JoséValim, I'll be damned ... on a new environment, I cannot reproduce the issue! I'm loading up the original environment to see if I can still reproduce it there.

Comment: I could not reproduce it on my original environment either. However, I think I know what might have caused it. When I started the development server, `config.reconfirmable` was set to true, and I don't think I restarted it, after changing it in the initializer. Sounds plausible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It was not a problem with Devise, but with me not restarting the development server.